# Vector-based brush with Gaussian blob

Tags: opengl, graphics, opencl, draw, brush

I need to render simple brush stokes, with support for the following properties:

- A circular brush head, with feather and opacity
- Resolution independent (e.g. Drawing on a down-scaled version of the image should be indistinguishable from drawing on the full-resolution image and downscale the result).
- Real-time rendering (it should be very efficient)
- Software rendering should be an option (So I can reproduce the result without OpenGL)

I can also use C++ or OpenCL for this.

The input is given as a set of points and radius. The points are connected with straight lines. Supporting bezier curves would be nice.

What's the best / easiest way to implement this?

Comment: using GIMP or photoshop is probably the best way :D

Comment: Those tools do not render the brush strokes parametrically, and thus the rendering is not scale-independent.

Comment: You basically need vector graphics => inkscape / illustrator then. Are you asking how to implement inkscape rendering with OpenGL?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking how to implement the above functionality using OpenCL / OpenGL / C++.

Comment: You just need to draw triangles trails, OpenGL much better than OpenCL for that. The triangles must be filled with a fragment shader to provide scale-indipendent look and must use no textures.

Comment: @DarioOO, and how do I implement the feather effect of the brush in the fragment shader? How do I triangulate the brush strokes (given by linearly interpolated sampled mouse locations)?

Comment: 1) by using a texture wich is not scale indipendent
2) using a spline among mouse locations given each location is far enough (in time and space) from the next one. (too dense location are bad looking). Then you offset the spline along its normal by brush radius.

Comment: Do you suggest to draw and blend the brush tip multiple times? This is not efficient as computing the distance from the stroke center.

Comment: nope. You create a triangle spline along mouse path. This is not blending but a single shape that is changed everyframe (pretty efficient: just like a particle system)